# Replace quotes with open and close html tags

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have the following string:

```
'something can go here' and there some more text 'then some more here'
```

That I would like to become:

```
<pre>something can go here</pre> and there some more text <pre>then some more here</pre>
```

I know you can do:

```
 str_replace($replace, $with, $from);
```

But as both ends are the same symbol thats not going to work, what is the best way to get around this?

Comment: your string contain '' also at both place. are you just highlighted that two parts by putting them in ''.? And also always your string is like this or words and sentence will  change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine for you:

(Just use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and then you can replace the quotes as you wanted)

```
<?php

    $str = "'something can go here' and there some more text 'then some more here'";
    echo $str = preg_replace("/'(.*?)'/", "<pre>$1</pre>", $str);

?>
```

output:

```
<pre>something can go here</pre> and there some more text <pre>then some more here</pre>
//^^^                     ^^^^^^                          ^^^^^                   ^^^^^^
```